# Is there a way to get notified when a packet arrives over socket rather than keep on polling using recv()

Tags: linux, sockets

I have an application which keeps waiting for a packet over UDP. I do this using `recv()` call (NON-BLOCKING).

The application is multi-threaded, the purpose of other threads is to do some processing when the particular packet is received.

Since, in IDLE times, one thread keeps on polling for packet the CPU usage for 1 core is near 100%.

Therefore, to remove this intensive polling (and in general, for information) is there a way such that **I can get notified when the packet is received?** i.e. something similar to **registering a parse callback which can be called when any packet is received on that socket**.

P.S. I cannot have a delay of more than 5 ms between successive `recv()` calls.

OS Info : Debian 8u2, Kernel 3.16
Platform : Intel i3, x86_64

Comment: You can simply create this polling yourself. Add another thread which waits with `select()` and then call the callback routine. You also might have a look at http://libevent.org/

Comment: Thanks @jofel, I think [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) will do the work for me. I'll try it and post my observations.

Comment: Hey @jofel, the solution with `select()` works!! :) Can you post your comment as answer, so that I can accept it and close this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways how to get informed about received data.

#### select()

As mentioned in comments above `select` is an old and highly portable mechanism how to wake up a thread when socket is ready for reading and writing. The `select` has a bad performance if the number of socket is high because the sets of sockets cannot be reused between calls and it is required to iterate over whole set of sockets to find which is readable or writable. The sockets added to set for `select` should not be written and read from another thread so ot is difficult to use it in multithreaded application. An example how to use it is in `man select`.

#### poll()

It is a newer mechanism that `select`. It eliminates some `select` performance drawbacks but it some are still present like iterating through set of sockets to find which socket is readable or writable. `poll` is portable across unixes and windows supports it since Vista.

#### epoll()

`epoll` is a modern linux specific polling method. It is quite new (added to kernel in 2002). It eliminates almost all of `poll` and `select` performance problems. The only drawback is that it is not portable outside linux ecosystem. Some OSes have own proprietary polling mechanism as well. For example FreeBSD has `kpoll`.

#### library based polling

The low level access to `select`, `poll`, `epoll` can be encapsulated and a library may provide unified API for all of these methods. The well know library providing that is http://libevent.org/